# Android, how to Share an image file with messenger

Tags: android, facebook, file-sharing

Hello evrybody i'm tryng to share an image on messenger but i don't know why my code doesen't work, I've followed the official guide, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android
someone can told me why doese'nt work?

```
public void sendMessage(){
    Bitmap adv= takePic(HomeActivity.livelloCurrent.getNumeroLivello());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    adv.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        new FileOutputStream(f).write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setType(mimeType);
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg"));
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<---MY TEXT--->.");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.orca");
    try {
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Install Facebook Messenger", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   /** //withSDK-->// ShareToMessengerParams shareToMessengerParams = ShareToMessengerParams.newBuilder(ContentUri, mimeType).build();
    MessengerUtils.shareToMessenger(this, REQUEST_CODE_SHARE_TO_MESSENGER, shareToMessengerParams);**/
}
```

Im sure that the file creation work  cause i have tested it . in testing I get the following error from messenger "Sorry, Messenger was not able to process the file". 
how can i solve ?

Comment: Call `flush()`, `getFD().sync()`, and `close()` on the `FileOutputStream` after `write()`. Someday, switch to using `FileProvider` instead of `Uri.fromFile()`, as `fromFile()` will not work on Android 7.0+ devices once you set your `targetSdkVersion` to 24 or higher. Note that not all apps support *both* `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM` on the same `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`. And get rid of `setPackage()`, so you can [share where the user wants](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/06/28/share-where-the-user-wants.html).

Comment: i'have  called,  `flush()`, `getFD().sync()`, and `close()` on the `FileOutputStream` after write() , but still not work, i have also  removed `EXTRA_TEXT`

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg")
```

with:

```
Uri.fromFile(f)
```

Comment: i have this fatal Exception on log  console 

 `android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/temporary_file.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()  `

Comment: @Rachid: That is the problem that I mentioned in my first comment. You cannot use `Uri.fromFile()` on Android 7.0+ with a `targetSdkVersion` of 24 or higher. One option is to go into your `build.gradle` file and lower your `targetSdkVersion` to 23. Another option is to rework all of this to use `FileProvider`, so you are serving your files using that instead of trying to pass around a `Uri` that you get from `Uri.fromFile()`.

Comment: Thankyou soo much  have solve my problem :) :) using FileProvider

Comment: @Rachid: Perhaps Facebook only supports `EXTRA_STREAM`. As I wrote in my original comment, not all apps support *both* `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM` on the same `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.